# Re-assigning an object variable when its lock is acquired

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Does the following code make sense:

Thread A:

```
synchronized(mObj) {
    return mObj.x;
}
```

Thread B:

```
synchronized(mObj) {
    mObj = new Object();
}
```

In particular, is it guaranteed that both synchronized sections will always be mutually exclusive?

Comment: The lock is *not* on the variable, only the object.

Comment: A variable used as a lock should be declared `final`, to avoid this kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

No synchronized is not properly implemented here.

Every Object has a lock while execution thead acuire the lock and release it once it is done then the next thread will acuire who is waiting for that.

```
mObj = new Object();
```

reassigning new Object will make conflict on that.

Let assume a scenario - where 1st thread T1 is executing the synchronized section by acquiring the lock and thread t2 is waiting to get the lock which has acquired by thread T1. Now thread T1 reassign the `mObj` object with a new `Object` and leave the synchronized section by releasing the object (Old object) lock and thread t2 is now able to acuire the lock and get enter into the synchronized block.

At this point if thread T3 is trying to execute the synchrnized the block, "is the thread T3 able to acquire the Lock?". Answer is Yes. `synchronized(mObj)` now `mObj` reference is refering a new Object and no One has acquired the lock, so T3 can do it. so This is conflicting situation .

Comment: Your scenario is not really problematic. What is problematic is if a first thread acquires the lock, enters the synchronized section, reassigns the variable, and then another thread is able to enter the synchronized section, even though the first one hasn't left it yet, because the threads are now synchronized on two different objects.

Comment: umm Not exactly I thought a little complex scenario. hehe your problem statement is short or impressive.

Comment: I posted my comment before you introduced the last paragraph. You don't need 3 threads to illustrate the problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

The lock is *not* on the variable, only the object.

Here is a schedule that shows this is *not* "thread safe" because the resulting schedule is not guaranteed.

```
mObj = X       
synchronized(mObj) // B1 -> mObj evaluates to X
   mObj = Y        // B2
   DoSomeWork()    // B3
synchronized(mObj) // A1 -> mObj MAY evaluate to either X or Y
                   //       because the evaluation of the variable is NOT
                   //       within scope of the synchronization. If it
                   //       evaluates to Y then it is NOT synchronized on X.
   return mObj.x   // A2 -> May or may not be mutually exclusive wrt B3
                   //       (That is, neither case is "guaranteed".)
```

I've added a "DoSomeWork" at the end of the "Thread B" synchronized context to draw my argument, but I think the same logic/argument - that of it "may be X or Y" - can be applied without such and thus argued that the two synchronization blocks are *not* guaranteed to be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

For your question "is it guaranteed that both synchronized sections will always be mutually exclusive"
Yes it will be mutually exclusive but not the way someone want.

Scenario 1: Lets say Thread1 got the monitor object and get inside the synchronize block first then obviously Thread2 will wait and reassigning mObj wont have any effect. Happy scenario :)

Scenario 2: Thread 2 gets the monitor lock and goes inside the synchronized block first and Thread 1 is waiting for mObj. Now when you reassign mObj to new object mObj1 it will change the monitor object and which will lead Thread 1 waiting for monitor lock for forever because when Thread2 will come out of synchronized block it will release lock for monitor object mObj1 not mObj. That's why i said, it's still mutually exclusive but not the way someone want :).

Scenario 3: If you are using wait-notify solution and then you do the same thing it will be catastrophically and cause you illeagalMonitorstate exception for the same reason as you are trying to wait or notify on some monitor on which you don't have lock/synchronized block as you reassigned the obj.